# Read customed corpus in three column format for pos tagging using NLTK

Tags: nltk, corpus, pos-tagger

I have corpus in txt extention with like this below format:

```
Mike NNP B-PERSON
Noah NNP I-PERSON
eats VB O
donuts NN O
Sarah NNP B-PERSON
Larsson NNP I-PERSON
comes VB O
from IN O
Stockholm NN B-GPE
```

I want to read the file to train POS tag (take the words and POS tagger only) like reading a file with a bracket extension (already in a tree format). I tried to change the corpus to something like this in to str format using iteration:

```
(NNP Mike) (NNP Noah) (VB eats) (NN donuts) (NNP Sarah) (NNP Larsson) (VB comes) (IN from) (NN Stockholm)
```

But, when i use tagged_sents() function for it, there is an error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'tagged_sents'
```

How to read it correctly? Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ConllChunkCorpusReader`, I believe it would be something like this snippet below given that you have your corpus text file in the root of the project. Update the `chunk_types` accordingly.

```py
from nltk.corpus.reader import ConllChunkCorpusReader 
chunk_types = ('PERSON', 'GPE')
corpusReader = ConllChunkCorpusReader('./','*.txt', chunk_types)
print(corpusReader.iob_words())
```

This will give you list of tuples, which you can loop through to collect the POS tags..

```py
pos_tags = [postag for token, postag, label in corpusReader.iob_sents()]
```

Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nlp-customization-using-tagged-corpus-reader/